# "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when runnning a Nuxt.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I use:

- Node.js v6.14.2
- NPM 6.0.1
- Ubuntu 16.04

When I try to run a project, I get this error:

```
npm run dev


node_modules/nuxt/lib/core/module.js:14
  async ready() {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ostap/Стільниця/vue-photogram/node_modules/nuxt/lib/core/index.js:2:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-photogram@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-photogram@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ostap/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T16_35_55_903Z-debug.log
```

What is the reason behind that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Node.js version was too old. Upgrade solved this problem.